# Unknown amount of the nodes in yml - how to parse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

In an application I have this:

```
def get_debt_for_month(api_requests_count)
  case api_requests_count
  when 0..50
    5
  when 50..100
    9
  when 100..200
    13
  # and so on
  end
end
```

Obviously, having that hardcoded isn't a good idea. How would I do that? I figure the best way is that the prices should be moved to an yml file, but how why I parse it dynamically, given that the amount of the cases isn't known and can vary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no gaps in the range, just use the starting value...

```
# data.yml
0: 5
51: 9
101: 13
```

and then your method...

```
def get_debt_for_month(api_request_count)
  thresholds = YAML.load_file('data.yml')
  thresholds.sort.select{|e| e[0] <= api_request_count}.last[1]
end
```